# Cron Job + Twitter

Tags: php, unix, cron, twitter

Every hour starting from 12:30 (and going on to 1:30, 2:30, etc) my app will post a static tweet. I am currently using themattharris's twitter API. I have a cron job as well.

```
30 * * * *   php -q /home1/USER_NAME/public_html/twitter/index.php
```

The issue I am having is that the PHP code works when I manually refresh index.php & my cron job semi-works. The email I get from my cron job is:

```
Error 200
```

What I like to know is, how can I get my cron to work? I do not have any errors in my cron job.

```
include 'tmhOAuth/tmhOAuth.php';

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => 'XXX',
    'consumer_secret' => 'XXX',
    'user_token' => 'XXX',
    'user_secret' => 'XXX',
));

// Bahrain's time zone
date_default_timezone_set ('Asia/Riyadh');

// Set status message
$timezone= date("g:i");
$tweetMessage = "It's now" .$timezone. "in Bahrain";

//Response
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array('status' => $tweetMessage));

//Do something if the request was unsuccessful    
if ($response != 200) {
    echo 'Error 200';
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of `$tmhOAuth->response` after the error? See https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/tmhOAuth.php#L805

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
30 * * * * /usr/bin/php '/home1/USER_NAME/public_html/twitter/index.php'
```

that is the correct syntax, however it looks like in your code you are actually expecting a response from a page, which won't work if using cron.

You could do like you said below and use wget to get the actual URL, or the other option would be to use Curl to actually post and request that URL.  If you go with Curl, you would be able to use the standard cron since Curl would actually receive the response.

Comment: With JustHost, the way they have set up their cron job is similar to this:
 _   _   _   _   _
|_| |_| |_| |_| |_|

COMMAND: ---

The 5 boxes indicate min, hour, daily, monthly, yearly (Which are drop downs)

The Command line is simply the location of where my script is, in this case "www.domainname.com/twitter/index.php"

Comment: Ya, I think many hosts are like that and it bugs me.  I dislike that method because that puts your cron job out on a publicly accessible page where anyone that happens to request that page is running that script.  If that is the case, sometimes I will pass in a parameter to the script like www.domainname.com/twitter/index.php?arg1=121.  This way inside the script, you can validate someone didn't just hit that page .../twitter/index.php and run the cron.  I think in general its a better practice to have your jobs not be a page that is served on your webserver and have them in another folder.

Comment: Well I've solved the issue, everything was fine just my command wasnt. The command I've used is:
wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.DOMAINNAME.com/twitter/index.php