# Dynamically create cron jobs with php

Tags: php, cron

I need to do tweets on twitter through php on time ,day set by user. For that i am planning to use Cron jobs that is created dynamically through php .

Can any body please tell me how can i create cron jobs through PHP only.

Answer (score 0):

Set cron url in your server .Also set Interval.

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't You Use Cronjob ?  [Cron Job + Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635897/cron-job-twitter)

if you want to create cron jobs  through only PHP, You have to run the php file by means of you have to trigger.

your main index.php file of website's.

```
<?php
 if (hour == 14) include cron.php and call function or class method etc.
?>
```